# Hide - Show Button when the result is 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

So I have this function I know how it works but I wanted to ask you guys for help, because I want to make a function that when a variable's result is 0, then I will have a button that will hide all the 0 results. This function is intended for a table (the users will put some numbers, if the number is 0 then I want the button, so the zeros will hide (there will be a lot of zeros)).

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("p1");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Button</button>
<h2 id="p1">Hide-show<h2>
```

Comment: How is the table structured? Where is the result coming from?

Comment: why don't you use toggle function ?

Comment: The `display` toggle already works, and the rest isn't clear enough

Comment: Also, it is not clear whether you want reactivity based in the value of the variable, like would VueJS do.

Comment: it will be a just simple table. For now i dont mind to just have a parseFloat(prompt()); so i will give the number 0 and the function will work

Comment: as others already mentioned, can you make the question more clear, please? tell us exactly what you want to achieve after doing exactly what and when and etc.

Comment: where are those zeros ? How does the table even hold the numbers ? Kindly, take your time to clarify further more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean

```
document.querySelectorAll(".someClass").forEach(
  ele => ele.style.display = ele.innerText === "0" ? "none": "block"
);
```

or

```
document.querySelectorAll(".someClass").forEach(
  ele => if (ele.innerText === "0") ele.innerText = ""
);
```

jQuery versions in the dupe

Answer (score 1):

Because you have tagged the answer with "jQuery", I would like to improve @mplungjan answers with the jQuery syntax, where you have the [hide](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [show](https://api.jquery.com/show/) functions:

```
$(".someClass").hide()
```

In your case, you can use an attribute:

```
<table>
<tr data-value=0>...</tr>
</table>
```

Then you can select all elements with that attribute and show/hide them at once:

```
$('[data-value="0"]').hide()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42302644/how-to-hide-span-if-it-text-is-0-using-jquery